# How to run a Web Browser as a Daemon on a Server (without GUI)?

Tags: batch-file, browser, scripting

I wish to have a webbrowser that runs as a daemon on my linux server. The browser should have an application interface so that I can write a script that sends those commands to the browser (pseudocode):

```
set viewport size to 1024x768
turn javascript on
turn cookies off
enable loading of images
load http://facebook.com
wait for execution of javascript (max 10 sec)
scroll down 200 pixels
move mouse-pointer to 280,500 (relative to viewport)
wait again for execution of javascript (max 10 sec)
get browser content as DOM (encoded as tree of JSON object)
store viewport content as image to the file system
emulate click'n'drag from x,y=10,15 to 20,70 (coordinates relative to element with id="abc")
```

There are solutions (for example perl-modules) for loading the html-code of a webpage into a string, and there are also solutions that convert html-strings into DOM-object-trees. Loading of embedded images and following link is easy too.

But I did not find a solution that was able to execute javascript (and I don't want to write a javascript-emulator). There are many websites that use techniques like AJAX to load content on demand, and I find it really hard to get those contents by executing a script running on a server.

And I have no idea what I should do to generate a screenshot of a webpage without displaying the webpage on a GUI. I want a script on an GUI-less server to do this for me.

All common web browsers can execute javascript and they also can display web content in a graphical viewport. But is there also a browser that can do this as a daemon that is controlled by an external script using a well defined API? Maybe there is an add-on for firefox that turns it into a daemon?

Comment: [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)

Comment: Are there any alternatives to phantomjs? I installed it, but it crashes. See https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12183

Answer (score 0):

I have been using selenium-firefox driver in a maven job running via Jenkins on a remote slave connected via a Windows service. I have seen process explorer launch the firefox process, perform the selenium automation and quit.

Amongst the requirements you state, I'm not sure if selenium supports JSON encoding. But it probably does everything else and it will be easy to get the JSON part working too.